# Oracle - Sub query within Regexp_Like

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

Oracle: There is a "CUSTOMER" table and "EXCEPTION_KEYWORDS" table. 
I want to select the customers where the name contains any keyword from the Exception_keywords table.

I tried using a sub query inside Regexp_Like but getting error:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (STD_NAME,(Select KEYWORD from EXCEPTION_KEYWORDS),'i');
```

Note: I need solution only using Regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly `JOIN` those tables and use `regexp_like()` within the `ON` clause :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM CUSTOMER 
  JOIN EXCEPTION_KEYWORDS 
    ON REGEXP_LIKE (STD_NAME,KEYWORD,'i');
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=08c1134d1e910460d3779bc355e7d423)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks much for your solution and the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an exists query using `LIKE` and `lower()`

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER  c 
    WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM 
         EXCEPTION_KEYWORDS e 
 WHERE lower(c.STD_NAME) like '%'||lower(e.KEYWORD)||'%' );
```

Comment: Hi, 
I already solved in the same fashion but I want to know whether Oracle allows subquery inside a Regexp_like . If yes, what is the syntax?

Comment: @RamananB : The answer to your question is yes, Oracle allows subqueries inside `Regexp_like`. But it returns multiple rows in your case and hence not possible to write it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Check existance

```
SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE EXISTS (select null from EXCEPTION_KEYWORDS where REGEXP_LIKE (STD_NAME,KEYWORD ,'i'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be using `regexp_like()` with `listagg()` function :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM CUSTOMER 
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (STD_NAME,
 (SELECT LISTAGG(KEYWORD,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY KEYWORD) list 
    FROM EXCEPTION_KEYWORDS),'i');
```

Comment: Hi, It didn't work. Got error like 'Too many values' in spite of using Listagg. May be the output should be concatenated with braces and single quotes to meet Regexp Parameter 2 in the syntax. Anyways this wouldn't be an ideal way for the problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: it is working  fine , i have tried again.it is not working good in 11g but in 12c it is working fine